# Load Error with Hierarchy / Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
\- app
  \- models
  \- services
    \- recommended_action
      |- base.rb
      |- other_recommended_action.rb
    |- random_service.rb
```

In my application.rb, I'm autoloading the recommended_action directory via

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/services/recommended_action
)
```

My `base.rb` file looks like this:

```
module RecommendedAction
  class Base
    def initialize(attributes = {})
      # assign the attributes
    end
  end
end
```

However, whenever I try to load the rails console, I'm getting the following error:

`Unable to autoload constant Base, expected /Users/justin/project/app/services/recommended_action/base.rb to define it (LoadError)`

What am I missing?

Comment: everything in app is autoloaded by default. get rid of that configuration.

Comment: without the change to application.rb, it was throwing a error that `RecommendedAction` was undefined.  Hmm.

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: Getting these errors on rails 4.1.7 - ruby 2.0

Comment: i don't have any issues https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/compare/service_folder?expand=1

Comment: Weird -- i'm getting the issue when I try to load console.  This is in a project that was upgraded from rails 3 to rails 4, so maybe I've got a legacy setting that's incorrect.